# How to get list of fields that are shown in a particular view of that object in apex?

Tags: apex, customsetting

I have a list custom setting which has 4-5 views and each view has different set of fields that are shown. I want to get these set of fields per view something like:

> List= CustomSetting.getFieldsFromView(ViewA);

where ViewA is one of the view and CustomSetting is the list custom setting

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can access the custom setting values in the following ways

Custom settings have their own instance methods to allow easy access. It looks like the getInstance() and getValues() method returns the same object. I typically use the getInstance() method as it makes more sense to me. You access a record by using the value in the Name column (you cannot use the ID or other columns):

```
CustomSetting__c code = CustomSetting__c.getInstance('ViewA');
```

To return a map of data sets defined for the custom object (all records in the custom object), you would use:

```
Map<string,CustomSetting__c> mapCustomSetting = CustomSetting__c.getAll();
```

Alternatively you can return the map as a list:

```
List<CustomSetting__c> listCustomSetting = CustomSetting__c.getAll().values();
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sukesh, I don't want all values, but only those records which are filtered in particular views.